# Sorting a dictionary and outputting the key which corresponds to the highest value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to output the name of the pet which corresponds to the highest value:

```
import operator
pets = {"Dog":3, "Cat":5, "Rabbit":0}
sorted_pets = sorted(pets.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
print (sorted_pets[0])
```

The code above outputs `['Cat', 5]`. How can I change it so it just outputs `Cat`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly a more pythonic alternative:

```
>>> max(pets, key=pets.get)
'Cat'
```

Comment: Wow, that's a much neater method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted_pets[0][0]
```

Try this.This should do it.

Comment: Thank you! How did I miss that?! So simple!